# Declaring singletons in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have this code for getting a singleton intance of my `Room` database but all over my code i get lint warnings when using the `Dao` that it could cause a null pointer exception because getInstance can return a nullable value

```
abstract class DatabaseInstance : RoomDatabase() {

    // ... Dao's

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: DatabaseInstance? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): DatabaseInstance? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(DatabaseInstance::class) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        DatabaseInstance::class.java, "my_database.db")
                        .allowMainThreadQueries().fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```

I tried seeing if I could use a private and public instance variable where the public would have a custom getter and do what getInstance does but I cant pass context into it.

Since `getInstance` is really never going to return null how can I adjust things so that the lint error's are gone?

And no I don't want to just suppress the lint error

Comment: if getInstance would never return null why you put getInstance() def returns optional? change it to return `DatabaseInstance` instead of `DatabaseInstance?` btw kotlin has another way of making singleton class you can google that out

Comment: Because it is returning `INSTANCE` which is nullable, though I suppose I could return `INSTANCE!!`....Didnt think about that until now

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I was also looking at `lateinit` but then lint gave me a warning saying `if (INSTANCE == null)` would always be false

Comment: In this case you can safely use  `!!`. It's not pretty, but it's definitel safe in this situation, and it solves your problem quicky.

Comment: Use the `lazy` property delegate instead of trying (and failing) to write your own lazy init code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getInstance(Context)` returns an optional type. Instead make it return `DatabaseInstance` using the `!!` operator on `INSTANCE`.

```
fun getInstance(context: Context): DatabaseInstance {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized(DatabaseInstance::class) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                DatabaseInstance::class.java, "my_database.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries().fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE!!
}
```

But keep in mind that your overall implementation is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
companion object {
    private val instance: DatabaseInstance = DatabaseInstance()
    fun getInstance(): DatabaseInstance {
        return instance
    }
}
```

Correct me if I'm worng, but I think your instance only will be initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) to return a non-null `DatabaseInstance` and avoid using the `!!` operator:

```
private var INSTANCE: DatabaseInstance? = null

fun getInstance(context: Context): DatabaseInstance {
    return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(DatabaseInstance::class) {
        INSTANCE ?: Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, DatabaseInstance::class.java, "my_database.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
                .also { INSTANCE = it }
    }
}
```

Source: [Pro-tips for Room](https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/697e543652b03d3d2a06703f5d6b44b5#file-datadatabase-kt-L37)